# Google sheets - VLOOKUP inside ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to do Vlookup inside an Array formula in Google Sheets.

I have two sheets, S1 and S2.

Each has 3 identical columns, Col A (Date), Col B(Name) and Col C(Payment-Type)

I would like to read the payment type from sheet 2 into sheet 1 based upon date and name combination match. Meaning if the date and name matches in sheet 2, return the Payment Type.

Here is my Vlookup formula,

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,FILTER('S2'!A2:C7,'S2'!A2:A7 = A2,'S2'!B2:B7 = B2),3,FALSE)
```

Above formula explained:

> S1 is sheet 1 and S2 is sheet 2
>
> A2 <- Date from sheet 1
>
> 'S2'!A2:C7    <-  Entire sheet 2 range
>
> 'S2'!A2:A7 = A2   <- Comparing sheet 2 dates with Date in A2 of sheet
>   1
>
> 'S2'!B2:B7 = B2  <- Comparing sheet 2 names with Name in B2 of sheet
>   1
>
> 3  <- Returning the third column value which is Payment Type if the
>   date and name match.

This works well. Here is a link to the spreadsheet with an example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tIlq_kBWlM1Stj_Iqoua2LswW2IUl7TBbhnFFhPX4uo/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to replace the Vlookup formulas on all rows with just one Array formula in the second row.

This is what I have now which is not working.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP($A$2:$A$7,FILTER('S2'!A$2:C$7,'S2'!$A$2:A7 = $A$2:$A$7,'S2'!$B$2:B7 = $B$2:B7),3,FALSE))
```

Please, can someone tell me what is wrong here? I am pretty poor with these formulas. Kindly refer the sheet I attached above. That will explain everything to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all contents of column C and then enter in C1

```
={"Payment Type"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), VLOOKUP($A2:A&B2:B,{'S2'!$A$2:A7&'S2'!$B$2:B7, 'S2'!$C$2:C7},2,FALSE),))}
```

See if that works?