# Vlookup a QR code cell in Google Sheets returns empty

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

In Google Sheets when searching for data of a row from another tab/sheet based on a `Vlookup` search, the cell that has a QR code returns empty.  **EXAMPLE IS HERE**: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jy8AVbSfgJRh5WAFNgEOAq-VvEuBbyMDk5js3EiiRf4/edit?usp=sharing

I have 4 tabs/sheets in Google Sheets:

1. (Sheet1-data) Gathers data from Google Forms.
2. (Sheet2-process) Serves to process the data from sheet one and is where the QR codes get generated.
3. (Sheet3-pivot) Gathers all data and adds an N/A automatically to empty cells and it's based on: ['No match' message in Google Sheets Vlookup results for cells with no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56431884/no-match-message-in-google-sheets-vlookup-results-for-cells-with-no-data).
4. (Sheet4-search) Performs a Vlookup search based on a value entered by the user and it's based on: [Search a value from another tab/sheet in google sheets based on cell reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56331808/search-a-value-from-another-tab-sheet-in-google-sheets-based-on-cell-reference).

---

The code for generating the QR in (Sheet2-process) is this:

```
={"QR";arrayformula( if( len(A2:A),IMAGE("https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=120x120&data="&ENCODEURL(
"-Tipo de Equipo: "&B2:B& char(10)& 
"-ID unico: "& F2:F& char(10)& 
"-# Serial: "&G2:G & char(10)&
"-Area: "&L2:L & char(10)),2)   ,""))}
```

---

The code for the QR column in (Sheet3-pivot) is this:

```
 =arrayformula(IF(LEN('Sheet1-data'!$A:$A), IF(Sheet2-process!M:M<>"",Sheet2-process!M:M,"N/A"),""))
```

---

And then, the code for the search is something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(B3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
        VLOOKUP(B3, {Sheet3-pivot!AN:AN, Sheet3-pivot!A:BR}, 
                    {69,70},0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ),
    IF(C3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
        VLOOKUP(C3, {Sheet3-pivot!AK:AK, Sheet3-pivot!A:BR}, 
                    {69,70},0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ), 
    IF(D3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
        VLOOKUP(D3, {Sheet3-pivot!AR:AR, Sheet3-pivot!A:BR}, 
                    {69,70},0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ),
    IF(E3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
        VLOOKUP(E3, {Sheet3-pivot!W:W, Sheet3-pivot!A:BR}, 
                    {69,70},0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ),
    IF(F3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
        VLOOKUP(F3, {Sheet3-pivot!Z:Z, Sheet3-pivot!A:BR}, 
                    {69,70}, 0)), CHAR(10))), "♦",),
                    ))))))
```

The search does return all values except for the QR code which would be the row 70 (it's the `...{69,70}...` ). The cell just appears empty as if there was nothing in the proper column of the pivot sheet.

The objective of the values searched in (Sheet4-search) is that they can be referenced on a future new sheet/tab with a printable report depending on what was searched.

My only guess so far is that it may be because the QR is an image. However, if for example, I use a simple `=BQ3` (A cell with a generated QR), the reference works perfectly.

Comment: The example sheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jy8AVbSfgJRh5WAFNgEOAq-VvEuBbyMDk5js3EiiRf4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to add it in array `{}` separately like:

[image: 0]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
        IF(B3<>"", {SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
            VLOOKUP(B3, {'Sheet3-pivot'!AN:AN, 'Sheet3-pivot'!A:BR}, 
                        {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,71},
 0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ); VLOOKUP(B3, {'Sheet3-pivot'!AN:AN, 'Sheet3-pivot'!A:BR}, 70, 0)},

        IF(C3<>"", {...............
```